# java.lang.ArrayStoreException: sun.reflect.annotation.TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy while integrating 2 projects

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit

I am trying to integrate 2 automation projects so that we can have a single project
First project contains : spring boot and jpa dependency
Second project contains : rest assured dependency

I added all dependencies of seconf project inyto the First one

But when I build my project I am getting

```
java.lang.ArrayStoreException: sun.reflect.annotation.TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseClassArray(AnnotationParser.java:724)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseArray(AnnotationParser.java:531)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseMemberValue(AnnotationParser.java:355)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotation2(AnnotationParser.java:286)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations2(AnnotationParser.java:120)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations(AnnotationParser.java:72)
    at java.lang.Class.createAnnotationData(Class.java:3521)
    at java.lang.Class.annotationData(Class.java:3510)
    at java.lang.Class.getAnnotation(Class.java:3415)
    at io.cucumber.spring.SpringBackend.lambda$loadGlue$1(SpringBackend.java:34)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:174)
    at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1380)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:580)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$7$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:270)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:175)
    at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1380)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:151)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:174)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:418)
    at io.cucumber.spring.SpringBackend.loadGlue(SpringBackend.java:35)
    at io.cucumber.core.runner.Runner.<init>(Runner.java:54)
    at io.cucumber.core.runtime.ThreadLocalRunnerSupplier.createRunner(ThreadLocalRunnerSupplier.java:51)
    at java.lang.ThreadLocal$SuppliedThreadLocal.initialValue(ThreadLocal.java:284)
    at java.lang.ThreadLocal.setInitialValue(ThreadLocal.java:180)
    at java.lang.ThreadLocal.get(ThreadLocal.java:170)
    at io.cucumber.core.runtime.ThreadLocalRunnerSupplier.get(ThreadLocalRunnerSupplier.java:43)
    at io.cucumber.junit.PickleRunners$NoStepDescriptions.run(PickleRunners.java:148)
    at io.cucumber.junit.FeatureRunner.runChild(FeatureRunner.java:135)
    at io.cucumber.junit.FeatureRunner.runChild(FeatureRunner.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber.runChild(Cucumber.java:200)
    at io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber.runChild(Cucumber.java:90)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber$RunCucumber.evaluate(Cucumber.java:235)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater$1.execute(IdeaTestRunner.java:38)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.TestsRepeater.repeat(TestsRepeater.java:11)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:35)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:235)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)
```

pom.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <groupId>est-automation</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.5.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> 
    </parent>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <spring-boot-starter-web.version>2.0.9.RELEASE</spring-boot-starter-web.version>
        <axon-sdk.version>2.0.5</axon-sdk.version>
        <lombok.version>1.18.2</lombok.version>
        <oracle-jdbc-driver.version>12.1.0.1.0</oracle-jdbc-driver.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <maven-compiler-plugin.version>3.10.1</maven-compiler-plugin.version>
        <maven-jar-plugin.version>3.2.2</maven-jar-plugin.version>
        
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>log4j-to-slf4j</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Spring Boot Started Web -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>log4j-to-slf4j</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Spring Data JPA -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Oracle JDBC driver -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc7</artifactId>
            <version>${oracle-jdbc-driver.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Lombok -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>6.10.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
            <version>6.10.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-spring</artifactId>
            <version>6.10.4</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
            <version>6.10.4</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>tech.grasshopper</groupId>
            <artifactId>extentreports-cucumber6-adapter</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.aventstack/extentreports -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
            <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
            <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.30</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Adding API dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
            <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
            <version>4.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-compiler-plugin.version}</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```